# Convert json response to java object

Tags: java, json

I have json response and I generated java code from this json by tools .But this  json object have key like @size ,@order etc ... ,So in my java code some invalid identifier has been generated. When I removed this @ symbol with java code I am able to catch the response of json value in my java object expect these value.

I am sure some json annotation is available to do this , means if the json key is not matching with java Object then we can map through this json annotation.

I tried with some Json annotation but is not worked for me and I confused which annotation should I used with   getter methods .

```
    here my json code below :-



  {
"HotelListResponse": {
    "cachedSupplierResponse": {
        "@cachedTime": "0",
        "@candidatePreptime": "111",
        "@matchedCurrency": "true",
        "@matchedLocale": "true",
        "@otherOverheadTime": "4",
        "@supplierRequestNum": "211",
        "@supplierResponseNum": "20",
        "@supplierResponseTime": "405",
        "@tpidUsed": "5001"
    },
    "cacheKey": "302c317:13443ffb599:-7712",
    "cacheLocation": "10.186.168.61:7302",
    "customerSessionId": "0ABAA83D-2C31-7913-4432-FFB599907714",
     "HotelList": {
        "@activePropertyCount": "237",
        "@size": "1",
        "HotelSummary": {
            "@ubsScore": "1867",
            "@order": "0",
            "hotelId": 127092,
            "name": "The Edgewater - A Noble House Hotel",
            "address1": "Pier 67, 2411 Alaskan Way",
            "city": "Seattle",
            "stateProvinceCode": "WA",
            "postalCode": 98121,
            "countryCode": "US",
            "airportCode": "SEA",
            "supplierType": "E",
            "propertyCategory": 1,
            "hotelRating": 4,
            "confidenceRating": 85,
            "amenityMask": 6259019,
            "tripAdvisorRating": 4,
            "tripAdvisorReviewCount": 590,
            "tripAdvisorRatingUrl": "http://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/4.0-12345-4.gif",
            "locationDescription": "Near Washington State Convention & Trade Center",
            "shortDescription": "<p><b>Location. </b> <br />The Edgewater - A Noble House Hotel is a business-friendly hotel located in central Seattle, close to Odyssey - The Maritime Discovery Center, Washington State Convention &",
            "highRate": 249,
            "lowRate": 186.75,
            "rateCurrencyCode": "USD",
            "latitude": 47.61252,
            "longitude": -122.35013,
            "proximityDistance": 11.898841,
            "proximityUnit": "MI",
            "hotelInDestination": true,
            "thumbNailUrl": "/hotels/1000000/20000/11200/11133/11133_73_t.jpg",
            "deepLink": "http://travel.ian.com/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&cid=55505&hotelID=127092&mode=2&numberOfRooms=2&room-0-adult-total=1&room-0-child-total=1&room-0-child-0-age=3&room-1-adult-total=1&room-1-child-total=1&room-1-child-0-age=5&arrivalMonth=8&arrivalDay=4&departureMonth=8&departureDay=5&showInfo=true&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD",
            "RoomRateDetailsList": {
                "RoomRateDetails": {
                    "roomTypeCode": 1160,
                    "rateCode": 1221260,
                    "maxRoomOccupancy": 2,
                    "quotedRoomOccupancy": 2,
                    "minGuestAge": 0,
                    "roomDescription": "City Lodge - Nonrefundable",
                    "promoId": 200803780,
                    "promoDescription": "7-Day Advance Purchase Special (Nonrefundable)",
                    "currentAllotment": 10,
                    "propertyAvailable": true,
                    "propertyRestricted": false,
                    "expediaPropertyId": 11133,
                    "rateKey": "f3525aff-9f4d-4d92-bc1c-144628fcaa30",
                    "nonRefundable": true,
                    "RateInfos": {
                        "@size": "1",
                        "RateInfo": {
                            "@rateChange": "false",
                            "@promo": "true",
                            "@priceBreakdown": "true",
                            "RoomGroup": {
                                "Room": [
                                    {
                                        "numberOfAdults": 1,
                                        "numberOfChildren": 1,
                                        "childAges": 3
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "numberOfAdults": 1,
                                        "numberOfChildren": 1,
                                        "childAges": 5
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "ChargeableRateInfo": {
                                "@commissionableUsdTotal": "373.5",
                                "@total": "441.74",
                                "@surchargeTotal": "68.24",
                                "@nightlyRateTotal": "373.5",
                                "@averageBaseRate": "249.0",
                                "@averageRate": "186.75",
                                "@maxNightlyRate": "186.75",
                                "@currencyCode": "USD",
                                "NightlyRatesPerRoom": {
                                    "@size": "1",
                                    "NightlyRate": {
                                        "@promo": "true",
                                        "@rate": "186.75",
                                        "@baseRate": "249.0"
                                    }
                                },
                                "Surcharges": {
                                    "@size": "1",
                                    "Surcharge": {
                                        "@amount": "68.24",
                                        "@type": "TaxAndServiceFee"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and I generated the java classes from above mention json by  this tool: http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/

So here how to map[ @key (value of key start with @) ] in our java classes. Initially java class have @identifier_name but java compiler not support variable name start with @ so I have to remove it.And then I am not able to map json value to this variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's usually helpful if you include what you already have - even if it doesn't work - as a starting point for answers. An example of the JSON would also be useful.

Comment: Also, please indicate what framework/API you are using to deal with Json.

Comment: Please mention your tool

Comment: I am very sorry for this , now I edit my question ,please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: That JSONgen Tool creates Java classes, but which framework do you use to do the actual parsing?